# NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys vs literal notation

Tags: objective-c

What are the differences between using NSDictionary/NSArray constructors and the literal notation?

```
NSDictionary *dict1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"bar", @"foo"];
NSDictionary *dict2 = @{ @"foo" : @"bar" };

NSArray *arr1 = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"one", @"two"];
NSArray *arr2 = @[ @"one", @"two" ];
```

What about accessing dictionary and array elements?

```
NSLog(@"%@", [dict1 objectForKey:@"foo"]);
NSLog(@"%@", dict2[@"foo"]);

NSLog(@"%@", [arr1 objectAtIndex:0]);
NSLog(@"%@", arr2[0]);
```

Is the difference purely readability, or is there a performance/behavior difference as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained [in the Clang documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html), the literal `@{}` and `@[]` forms are identical to `dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:` and `arrayWithObjects:count:`, which verify that no `nil` values are present.

Similarly, the subscript notations translate directly to `objectAtIndexedSubscript:`/`setObject:atIndexedSubscript:` and `objectForKeyedSubscript:`/`setObject:forKeyedSubscript:` (which can be implemented for your own classes if you so desire).

Compiling this code…

```
@import Foundation;
int main() {
    NSDictionary *dict1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"bar", @"foo", nil];
    NSDictionary *dict2 = @{@"foo" : @"bar"};
    NSString *result1 = dict2[@"bar"];

    NSArray *arr1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", nil];
    NSArray *arr2 = @[@"one", @"two"];
    NSString *result2 = arr2[1];
    return 0;
}
```

…and opening the binary with Hopper reveals this pseudocode, which is not perfect, but good enough to see what's going on:

[image: pseudocode]